# RDD pyspark splitting movie year

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have a csv file with three columns `movie ID`,`Movie name` and `Genres`.The movie name column also contains the year of the movie release and is placed inside parenthesis`()`.

I want to read the csv as an RDD line by line and parse the year from the second.

In a nutshell I want to collect the data about the number of movies released in any particular year.The output as collected post spitting operation looks as follows.I want the count of all the (year) in the following list

Sample row of csv file is represented as follows:

movie ID     movie name                   genres
    1        Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy

As of now I have mapped the read csv file to split function as:

```
moviez=sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/movies.csv")
year1=moviez.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).collect()
```

`year1` creates list where the movie year id one of its element(say (1995)).
How can I create a count of all such elements of this list( movie year )?

```
[u'movieId,title,genres',
 u'1,Toy', u'Story', u'(1995),Adventure/Animation/Children/Comedy/Fantasy', 
 u'2,Jumanji', u'(1995),Adventure/Children/Fantasy', 
 u'3,Grumpier', u'Old', u'Men', u'(1995),Comedy/Romance', 
 u'4,Waiting', u'to', u'Exhale', u'(1995),Comedy/Drama/Romance', 
 u'5,Father', u'of', u'the', u'Bride', u'Part', u'II', u'(1995),Comedy'
]
```

Any guidance and help in this matter is really appreciated.I am working on `pyspark` platform for this job.

Comment: Please look into using code formatting. `backticks` and 4 spaces indented code with newlines before and after the block helps.

Comment: can you elborate this `year 1 creates list where the movie year id one of its element(say (1995)).How can I create a count of all the elements of this list which are the movie year.`

Comment: The output looks like this [u'movieId,title,genres', u'1,Toy', u'Story', u'(1995),Adventure/Animation/Children/Comedy/Fantasy', u'2,Jumanji', u'(1995),Adventure/Children/Fantasy', u'3,Grumpier', u'Old', u'Men', u'(1995),Comedy/Romance', u'4,Waiting', u'to', u'Exhale', u'(1995),Comedy/Drama/Romance', .....].The map function creates a list out of the original RDD and year is one of its element.How can can I work from here to retrieve elements with movie year.

Comment: please add the output to question with proper formatting.

Comment: I have posted the list in my question itself.Is it clear now?

Comment: I observe you have a movie year in the elements starting with `(`. You possibly could filter all such elements and count the number of elements.

`len(filter(lambda x : x[0] == "(", list_in_question))` should give you the desired count. Is that what you are looking for ?